Validity of a property for a set of points on a bounded integer lattice
I believe that a property is true but I am not able to prove (or disprove) it. I first examplify it on a simple case.
We consider a set $I$ of five 2-dimensional points on a bounded integer lattice: $I=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$ with $x_{ij}\in\{0, 1, 2\}\;\forall j\in\{1, 2\}$. Moreover, we know that on each dimension $j\in\{1, 2\}$ and for each value $v\in\{0, 1, 2\}$ there is at least one of the point (i.e., $|\{x_i\in I\mbox{ such that } x_{ij}=v\}|\geq 1$) as in this example:

Property to prove or disprove: There necessarily exists a vector $v\in\mathbb R^{|I|}$ and a real $c\in\mathbb R$ such that  $\forall b\in\{1, 2, 3\}$ $\forall j\in\{1, 2\}$: $b + \sum_{x_i\in I,\,x_{i,j}<b} v_i = c$
In the above example, the property is true since we can take vector $v=(0,-1,0,0,-1)^T$ and $c=1$. Indeed:

if $b=1$ and $j=1$, $\{x_i\in I,\,x_{i,1}<1\}=\{x_1\}$ and we have $b + 0 =c$;
if $b=2$ and $j=1$, $\{x_i\in I,\,x_{i,1}<2\}=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and we have $b + 0-1+0 =c$;
if $b=3$ and $j=1$, $\{x_i\in I,\,x_{i,1}<3\}=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$ and we have $b + 0-1+0-1 =c$;
if $j=2$: easy to similarly check that the equality is still true.

To give you another example, in the following case:

the property is also true since we can take vector $v=(-1,1,-1,-1,-1)$ and $c=0$.
I would like to prove or disprove this property in the general case in which:

the number of points is not necessarily $5$;
the dimension of the points can be greater than $2$; and
$x_{ij}\in\{0,1, 2, ..., m\}$ and $b\in\{1, 2, ..., m+1\}$ (instead of just  $\{0, 1, 2\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$).

Any help would be welcome, even if it is just ideas and not a complete proof!

I found a counter example, $x_1=(0, 0)$, $x_2=(0, 2)$, $x_3=(1, 1)$, $x_4=(2, 1)$.
Indeed, vector $v$ must satisfy

for $j=1$ and $b=1$:  $b + v_1 + v_2 = c$ (A);
for $j=1$ and $b=2$:  $b + v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = c$  (B) $\Rightarrow v_3=-1$ (using (A));
for $j=1$ and $b=3$:  $b + v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4= c\Rightarrow v_4=-1$ (using (B));
for $j=2$ and $b=1$:  $b + v_1 = c$ (C) $\Rightarrow v_2=0$ (using (A));
for $j=2$ and $b=2$:  $b + v_1 + v_3 + v_4 = c\Rightarrow v_1=c$.

To sum up, we must have $v=(c, 0, -1, -1)$. However, this solution does not satisfy Equation (C). So there is no solution.

Can you elaborate a bit?

Yes, I edited my answer.
